# Why is Azure DevOps checking out a PR by commit rather than PR reference?

Tags: git, azure-devops, build, pull-request

My team is attempting to merge two repos into a monorepo for a variety of reasons. I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories) to get them into one. However, the UI gated-build YML, in an effort to reduce build time, attempts to only run tests against what has changed within the PR. This is done by grabbing the previous commit ID, setting it to a variable and then using that to execute the tests:

```
BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD~1) && echo testing branch $BRANCH
npm run branch && vitest run --changed $BRANCH
```

I kept getting the error `fatal: Needed a single revision`. Digging in, it's because ADO is pulling down the PR to build via commit ID, rather than pulling the PR by ref.

Previous logs that worked on the old repo:

```
git --config-env=http.extraheader=env_var_http.extraheader fetch --force --tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin  +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/8847/merge:refs/remotes/pull/8847/merge
```

New logs on new repo:

```
git --config-env=http.extraheader=env_var_http.extraheader fetch --force --tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin --depth=1 +f77dbabe86180eabf1a9a0ebe3450ed4afe67eab:refs/remotes/origin/f77dbabe86180eabf1a9a0ebe3450ed4afe67eab
```

Because it's pulling down by commit ID, it's only pulling that single commit, therefore there is no previous commits for `rev-parse` to grab and the error occurs.

Any idea why the PR build is pulling by commit rather than by PR ref like it did before? The build is still being kicked off by a PR, so what could possibly cause the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the `Depth=1` automatically appended.

You can edit the pipeline yaml -> click vertical 3 dots on the top right -> triggers -> Yaml Tab-> `Get sources` page, disable `shallow fetch` option.(for classic build pipeline, it's also in the Get sources page)

[image]

My PR pipeline for your reference:

[image]

Comment: I never would've found this. Thank you so much Wade!